# Lua: store unspecified number of items in return value

Tags: lua

```
function foo()
  return "a", "b", "c"
end

function bar()
  return foo()
end

function process()
  -- ...
end

function bar_store()
  local v = foo()
  process()
  return v
end

print(bar())        -- A
print(bar_store())  -- B
```

Result:

```
a   b   c           -- A
a                   -- B
```

How can I make B version act like a A version? In "bar_store" I need to call function than may return any number of return values, but I need to do some work after function call ("process" in my example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, answering your own question is a little bit lame, but:

```
function bar_store()
  local v = {foo()}
  process()
  return unpack(v)
end
```

Comment: If you found the answer, then you found it.

Comment: It happens.  Give yourself a check so it shows up as being answered.

Comment: There is no need to create a temp table to store the returns of foo(). You can do the following:     return process(foo())